# How to send contact form-data to API using mailkit (Angular 7 + .Net core web api)

Tags: .net, angular, angular7, asp.net-core-webapi, mailkit

I'm trying to submit contact form data to an api endpoint using mailkit. I have a website with a contact page and whenever someone fills out the contact form and hits send I want my website to send me an email. I have been stuck trying to solve this for weeks sadly(new to programming) and figured I'd reach out for some help.

I have checked youtube numerous times and cannot seem to find a complete tutorial anywhere on how to do this with .NET web api, mailkit, and angular 7.

I'll start off with my form html (pretty standard reactive form with validation):

```
  <form novalidate [formGroup]="contactForm" method="post" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(contactForm, contactForm.isValid)">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input  type="text" formControlName="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter name">
        <div [hidden]= "contactForm.controls.name.valid || contactForm.controls.name.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
          <span *ngIf="!contactForm.controls.name.valid"> Name is required!</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input  type="text" formControlName="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email">
        <div [hidden]= "contactForm.controls.email.valid || contactForm.controls.email.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
          <span *ngIf="!contactForm.controls.email.valid"> Email is required!</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Subject</label>
        <input  type="text" formControlName="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter subject">
        <div [hidden]= "contactForm.controls.subject.valid || contactForm.controls.subject.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
          <span *ngIf="!contactForm.controls.subject.valid"> Subject is required!</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Message</label>
        <textarea rows="3" type="text" formControlName="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter message"></textarea>
        <div [hidden]= "contactForm.controls.message.valid || contactForm.controls.message.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
          <span *ngIf="!contactForm.controls.message.valid"> Message is required!</span>
        </div>
      </div>


      <br>
      <button type="submit" [disabled]="!contactForm.valid" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>


    </form>

</div>
</section>
```

This is my contact component TS file:

```
userModel = new ContactFormComponent('','','','');
  public submitted: boolean;


  contactForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  onSubmit({value, valid} : {value: ContactForm, valid: boolean}){
    this.submitted = true;
    console.log(value, valid);
  }



  ngOnInit() {
    this.contactForm = this.fb.group({
      name:['',[Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
      email:['',[Validators.required]],
      subject:['', [Validators.required]],
      message:['', [Validators.required]]
    });
  }
```

I have gotten far enough to have the form log to console
[image]

this is in my api files, my email info model:

```
public class ContactInfo
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }        
        [Required]        
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Message { get; set; } 

    }
```

So far this is all I have in my controller:

```
public class emailController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task SendEmail([FromBody] ContactInfo contact)
        {

        }


    }
```

I do not have any mailkit endpoint created yet and I also do not know how to send the form data to the mailkit endpoint.

Could you please demonstrate how I can send this form data to a mailkit endpoint which would send the submitted data to my inbox?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code inside your `SendEmail` to send the email. Note that you should allow gmail to be used outside google domain by setting smtp in your gmail appropriate tab. here is the code to send email in aspnet core.

```
      var message = new MimeMessage();
      message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Recipient Name", "your@site.domaine"));
      message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("From Name", contact.Email));
      message.Subject = contact.Subject;
      message.Body = new TextPart(TextFormat.Html)
      {
        Text = contact.Message + 
              ". sent by: " + contact.Name + 
              " E-mail: " + contact.Email
      };
      using (var emailClient = new SmtpClient())
      {
        emailClient.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, false);
        emailClient.Authenticate("yougmail@gmail.com", "your_password");
        emailClient.Send(message);
        emailClient.Disconnect(true);
       }
```

Further, you'll need to use dependancy injection to get rid of disposing the SmtpClient object `using (var emailClient = new SmtpClient())`.